# Snowflake sql apply function once per partition

Tags: database, sql

In Snowflake, we can perform a window function like this:

`array_agg(a) over (partition by b) as c`

Since my partitions are large (big data), and my `f` is expensive, I need to make `f(c)` evaluate only once per partition. I've attempted:

`f(array_agg(a)) over (partition by b) as c`

but Snowflake says this doesn't work because `f` is not a window function.

I've also attempted

`f(array_agg(a) over (partition by b))`

but this seems to evaluate once per row as well.

How do I make `f` calculate only once per partition, then apply the result to the entire partition?